# How to obtain a list of the submodules of a module using Drush?

Tags: 7, drush

I want obtain trough drush a list of the availables submodules that comes inside a module.

So far this is what I have achieved:

```
drush pmi views_*
```

I obtain a detailed info for all the modules and themes starting with views in his name. (views_ui, views_bulk_operation, etc)

```
drush pml views | grep views_
```

In GNU/Linux systems I obtain a list of availables modules and themes starting with views_ in his name (views_ui, views_bulk_operation, etc)

But I can't obtain only the submodules of a module.

**Edit:** I'm using Drush 5.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A submodule is a convention rather than a 1st class citizen in Drupal. There are only Modules, Themes and Profiles in Drupal in Drupal 7, and perhaps you could list Configuration in Drupal 8.

A submodule in Drupal 7 at least is simply a convention that a Drupal 7 may contain within it additional module(s). Because a module in Drupal 7 is merely a folder with a given machine_name and an info file declaring that folder as a module to drupal.

The only thing I could think of attempting for your inquiry is to scan with the `drush pmi` outputs `path` value or even easier use a custom command with PHP and SQL  to scan the drupal `system` tables `path` entry for nested values and outputting the name of modules that share nested directory paths. Such a tool could be written as a drush script or command of course. If these details aren't enough to clue you in on it's implementation, if my schedule clears up I may reply with an implementation.

**Note:**

Scanning the directory paths could produce errorenous results. There's nothing stopping you from placing modules within other modules. Much in a similar way many people make custom: contrib, custom and features folder in their modules folder. Of course this would lead to confusing output.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I will wait to see if there is somebody that comes with a solution, if not I will take your advice.

Answer (score 4):

This information is available via the `pm-projectinfo` command:

```
$ drush pm-projectinfo views
 Name         :  Views (views) 
 Version      :  7.x-3.13      
 Extensions   :  views         
                 views_test    
                 views_ui
```

This command is available in Drush 8, and was first introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/766).  It is also available in [Drush Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_extras) for older versions of Drush.

Comment: pm-projectinfo is available only for drush8.

Comment: I'm using drush 5.10, there are a way to have this command in drush 5.10?

Comment: You should upgrade to Drush 8. Drush 5 and 6 are no longer supported. I think there is a standalone version of the pm-projectinfo commandfile somewhere, perhaps in an old PR, and that would probably work with Drush 5, but you're on your own if you go this route.

Comment: I updated the answer to include links to the older, unsupported versions of pm-projectinfo. Upgrading to Drush 8 strongly recommended, though.